# "Search Google for" options on PDF opened with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

On `Chrome` I was already able to select a text on `PDF` opened with it and search on Google just by selecting `Search Google for "..."` on the right click options. But it seems that this feature has been removed in the new version (Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)). Is that just my problem or all? What is the advantage of removing it? Or Is it because of that PDF contents has been restricted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature has been retrieved in Version 86.0.4240.75.